# How to pattern graphs on excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I wanted to ask how it is possible to pattern graphs on the same sheet in excel. I am aware already that one can pattern the same graph with all its formulas by copying the whole sheet.

However I am looking for the pattern-action inside the same sheet, as it would result as very useful for me.

That means that I do once the whole work, along some given rows, which includes some graphs.
This whole content shall then be repeatedly copied down the columns, with the condition that the new graphs are locked on to the new destinations... Not the old ones.

Thanks for all input.

Answer (score 0):

The series formulas for a chart contain absolute references and they cannot be changed to relative references. That means that when a chart is copied and pasted into the same worksheet, it will still refer to the original data range. The exception, as you noted, is copying the whole sheet, which will lead to the references being adjusted to the new sheet name.

When you copy a chart and paste it into the same sheet, then you need to adjust the references, either manually or with VBA.

Comment: Just as for completeness, would you mind describing how one would proceed doing it with VBA? Thanks.

Comment: The exact processing logic would need to be worked out based on the specific file. If a range that contains the chart and the source data is copied and pasted, the chart would retain its relevant position. VBA can then be used to establish the data for the chart from its position.